# Move docker-machine to another computer

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine, docker-swarm

I have a full working `docker-machine`/`docker-compose` cluter working in Google cloud. I control it from my laptop. I want to move Thame ability of control it to another laptop or computer. Which is the way of do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the machine had been setup on Google Cloud using docker-machine then the required files are inside the docker machine home directory:

- Windows: C:\Users\username.docker\machine\machines
- Linux/Mac: ~/.docker/machine/machines

Additionally, You can control the home directory of docker-machine with the environment variable: MACHINE_STORAGE_PATH

Step 1: Copy those files to the destination computer.

Step 2: Now adjust all config.json under .docker/machine/machines. There are full path expressions inside each file. Replace the path expressions matching your new location.

Comment: Thank you. It almost worked! Just one problem, after following your suggestion, I run `docker-machine ls` and everything is listed but with the error: `Unable to query docker- version:Unable to read TLS config: open  ...` this happens because the `ca. pem` files are been searched in my home folder in the original machine. How I can fix that?

Comment: Must be the config.json files under .docker/machine/machines/. There are full path expressions in there. Replace the path expressions matching your new location.

Comment: It worked! Could you add that to your answer, please?

Answer (score 0):

I tried doing the same thing and here is how I went about it and found a few things which is good to think about. Followed the great article written here https://medium.com/@cweinberger/docker-machine-export-and-import-34ae2899e9d7.

Essentially there is a tool now which gives you the opportunity to export and import docker machine settings with all the certificates between computers.

`npm install -g machine-share`

Then you go
`machine-export <machine-name>`
and
`machine-import <machine-name.zip>`
at the destination

It worked well, but it was something about the client API which did not quite work. After a while I realised it had to do with the name of the project folders being different, this generating different network names and that was the reason why I got zero containers back when I tried to run `docker-compose ps` on the new machine while being able to run the same on the old one and everything worked just fine.

A bit frustrating and something I did not consider in the beginning.